# How to set observer in facebook chat api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

i have successfully integrated facebook api for here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ .
i have also send message using chat api. i saw an iphone project which using the facebook api and xmpp here https://github.com/KanybekMomukeyev/FacebookChat.

they user Observer class to receive reply chat message and presence. how can i add observer in  chat api php code. need your help.